# duplicate key value violates unique constraint itemstaticlabel_item_id_f9405967_uniq

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

I know, this problem happens because the code is trying to add an entry to the database with a combination of unique keys that already exist. But my question is: why and how can I prevent this? It doesn't make sense to me that this is happening, given my logic.

I have this piece of code that basically stores some static label for an invoice. The idea is to create the label on the fly if it doesn't exist, instead of manually inserting it in a lot of places in the code.

Whenever an `Item` is generated, an `ItemInv` is also created, and by saving the latter, I check if a static label exists. If it doesn't, a new one is created. The code to get (or create) the static label is also called when displaying an Invoice / Draft.

The error seems to happen right there. The label doesn't exist, a new one is created, but somehow this happens twice? I mean, I really don't get why that code would try to add the same item two times. Could it be a thread issue?

I am not using `get_or_create` because some attributes on `ItemStaticInv` (`static_account_label`, `static_agreement_label`...) can be updated and not unique. Before creating the invoice, a draft has the same structure and the data can be changed, including these labels.

```
class ItemInv(managers.Model):
    """
    Relation between Item and Invoice
    """
    item = models.ForeignKey('Item')
    invoice = models.ForeignKey('Invoice')
    [...]

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('item', 'invoice')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        iteminv = super(ItemInv, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        # If the item does not have the static information, one should be created
        self.item.get_invoice_static(self.invoice)

        return iteminv


class Item(managers.Model):
    """
     Item to be put on an invoice
    """

    serial = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)  # Software license
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', verbose_name='Product')
    account = models.ForeignKey('Account', verbose_name='Account', related_name='items')
    [...]

    def get_invoice_static(self, document):
        try:
            return self.document_labels.get(invoice=document)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return ItemStaticLabel.objects.create(
                item=self,
                invoice=document,
                static_account_label=str(self.account),
                static_customer_label=str(self.account.customer),
                static_agreement_label=str(self.account.agreement)
            )


class ItemStaticLabel(managers.Model):
    """
    We must store static information about the Item on an invoice.
    """

    item = models.ForeignKey('Item', related_name='document_labels')
    invoice = models.ForeignKey('Invoice', related_name='item_labels')

    static_account_label = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    static_customer_label = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    static_agreement_label = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    static_expiration_label = models.DateField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('item', 'invoice')
```

This has several flaws, but this system was developed by someone else and is on production. The amount of structural changes I can do are pretty much limited. Therefore I gotta try to understand what is causing this issue.

```
Traceback:

File "/home/apps/sites/invoice/source/v3/models.py" in get_invoice_static
  1105.             return self.document_labels.get(invoice=document)

File "/home/apps/sites/invoice/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/apps/sites/invoice/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  380.                 self.model._meta.object_name


      During handling of the above exception (ItemStaticLabel matching query does not exist.), another exception occurred:



File "/home/apps/sites/invoice/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)


      The above exception (duplicate key value violates unique constraint "v3_itemstaticlabel_item_id_f9405967_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (item_id, invoice_id)=(1840, 1578) already exists.
) was the direct cause of the following exception:



File "/home/apps/sites/invoice/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/apps/sites/invoice/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/home/apps/sites/invoice/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/apps/sites/invoice/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/contextlib.py" in inner
  30.                 return func(*args, **kwds)

File "/home/apps/sites/invoice/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/apps/sites/invoice/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/apps/sites/invoice/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py" in get
  116.         context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)

File "/home/apps/sites/invoice/source/web/views/invoice.py" in get_context_data
  280.         context['document_html'] = services.document_to_html(obj)

File "/home/apps/sites/invoice/source/v3/services.py" in document_to_html
  1550.             'account': set_[0].get_invoice_static(document).static_account_label,

File "/home/apps/sites/invoice/source/v3/models.py" in get_invoice_static
  1112.                 static_agreement_label=str(self.account.agreement)

File "/home/apps/sites/invoice/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/apps/sites/invoice/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in create
  394.         obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)

File "/home/apps/sites/invoice/source/v3/managers.py" in save
  724.         super().save(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/apps/sites/invoice/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  808.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "/home/apps/sites/invoice/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  838.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "/home/apps/sites/invoice/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  924.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "/home/apps/sites/invoice/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  963.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "/home/apps/sites/invoice/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/apps/sites/invoice/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  1076.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "/home/apps/sites/invoice/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1107.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/apps/sites/invoice/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/apps/sites/invoice/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "/home/apps/sites/invoice/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py" in reraise
  685.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "/home/apps/sites/invoice/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /invoice-menu/customer/251/invoices/1578/
Exception Value: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "v3_itemstaticlabel_item_id_f9405967_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (item_id, invoice_id)=(1840, 1578) already exists.
```

#### View

```
class InvoiceDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Invoice
    template_name = 'invoice_detail.html'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'invoice_key'
    context_object_name = 'invoice'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(InvoiceDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    obj = context[self.context_object_name]

    obj = models.Invoice.objects.filter(pk=obj.pk).select_related(
            'customer',
            'customer__original',
            'currency',
    ).prefetch_related(
            'citems',
            'citems__assocs',
            'citems__assocs__product',
            'iteminv_set',
            'iteminv_set__item',
    ).first()

    context['document_html'] = services.document_to_html(obj)

    return context
```

### Services

```
def document_to_html(document):
    """
    Renders the invoice to html.
    """
    from v3.models import Item, Maintenance, Invoice, CustomInvoiceLine
    from web.collection_utils import collapse_list
    data = {}

    items = Item.objects.on_invoice(document)
    mains = Maintenance.objects.on_invoice(document)

    rows = get_invoice_product_rows(document)
    # merge the lists
    rows['itemrows'].extend(rows['mainrows'])
    include_summary = len(rows['itemrows']) > 0 and not Invoice.objects.filter(creditted_by=document)

    # calc VAT lines
    vats = {}
    for ir in rows['itemrows']:
        row = ir['line']
        vat = ir['objs'][0].vat
        rate = ir['objs'][0].vat_rate
        total = (Decimal(rate / 100) * ir['rowtotal']).quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)
        try:
            vats[vat]['rownums'].append(row)
            vats[vat]['total'] += total
        except:
            vats[vat] = dict(rownums=[row, ], message=ir['objs'][0].vat_message, total=total, rate=rate)

    for mr in rows['mainrows']:
        row = mr['line']
        vat = mr['objs'][0].vat
        rate = mr['objs'][0].vat_rate
        total = (Decimal(rate / 100) * mr['rowtotal']).quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)
        try:
            vats[vat]['rownums'].append(row)
            # Changed it to not add any  value  because that will produce wrong vat output.
            vats[vat]['total'] += 0
        except:
            vats[vat] = dict(rownums=[row, ], message=mr['objs'][0].vat_message, total=total, rate=rate)

    for cr in rows['citemrows']:
        row = cr['line']
        vat = cr['obj'].vat
        rate = cr['obj'].vat_rate
        total = (Decimal(rate / 100) * cr['rowtotal']).quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)
        try:
            vats[vat]['rownums'].append(row)
            vats[vat]['total'] += total
        except:
            vats[vat] = [row, ]
            vats[vat] = dict(rownums=[row, ], message=cr['obj'].vat_message, total=total, rate=rate)

    vats = [(k, collapse_list(v['rownums']), v['message'], v['total'], v['rate']) for (k, v) in vats.items()]
    vats = sorted(vats, key=lambda x: x[1])

    # Gather data for the license agreement overview
    # A list of lists, where the inner lists contain items that match on product and account
    matched_item_sets = []

    items = list(items) + list([m.serial for m in mains])
    for item in items:
        # Find a set to add this item to
        for set_ in matched_item_sets:
            if item.product == set_[0].product and item.account == set_[0].account:
                if item not in set_:
                    set_.append(item)
                break
        else:
            # No matching set found. Create a new one
            matched_item_sets.append([item])

    # Package the item sets nicely with meta information
    summary = []
    for set_ in matched_item_sets:
        summary.append({
            'account': set_[0].get_invoice_static(document).static_account_label,
            'owner': set_[0].get_invoice_static(document).static_customer_label,
            'agreement': set_[0].get_invoice_static(document).static_agreement_label,
            'product': set_[0].product,
            'licenses': collapse_list(set_),
        })

    data['inv'] = document
    data['lines'] = rows['itemrows']
    data['citems'] = rows['citemrows']
    data['vats'] = vats
    data['lagree'] = summary
    data['includeSummary'] = include_summary
    data['cilines'] = CustomInvoiceLine.objects.filter(invoice=document, on_invoice=True)

    data['base_url'] = settings.SITE_BASE_URL
    tpl = document.template
    tpl = DjangoTemplate(tpl.content)
    return tpl.render(Context(data))
```

Comment: Please show the view where the error is occurring.

Comment: @Alasdair I have done it. I am afraid it'll get too complex to undestand. There are a lot of dependencies in this project (and lots of legacies).

Comment: Have you figured out whether it's a race condition (different requests trying to create the same object at once) or does it happen when you do a single request by itself? The [`get_or_create`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11.6/django/db/models/query.py#L453) code does an extra lookup when it gets the integrity error, to try to fetch the newly-created object. Note that `get_or_create` allows you to specify defaults, so you might be able to use it.

Comment: As an aside, I would avoid calling `set_[0].get_invoice_static(document)` three times in a row inside `summary.append()`, but I don't think that's the problem here.

Comment: I didn't know about this defaults option for `get_or_create`. I'll look into it. It happens with only one user. What you said about calling `get_invoice_static` makes sense and that could be the problem. Eitherway, those are unnecessary calls.